# could not connect to server (https://code.ros.org)

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi i am trying to download ros-pkg but i constantly get this error-> could not connect to server (https://code.ros.org). What should i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12197/could-not-connect-to-server-(https://code.ros.org)/) by [Ruchi Dhiman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1486/ruchi-dhiman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2011-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use one of the [mirrors](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Mirrors) ... ROS goes down from time to time.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1